# Finding number of real solution of $4^x-2^{2+x}\cos(e^x)+1=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, logarithms, exponential-function

> Finding number of real solution of $4^x-2^{2+x}\cos(e^x)+1=0$

Try:$$(2^x)^2-4\cos(e^x)(2^x)+1=0$$

$$2^x=\frac{4\cos(e^x)\pm \sqrt{16\cos^2(e^x)-4}}{2}$$

$$2^x=2\cos(e^x)\pm \sqrt{4\cos^2(e^x)-1}>0$$

Could some help me to solve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going about this wrong.  You'll never be able to find explicit formulas for the solutions -- neither will anyone else, unless I'm badly mistaken.  The idea is to analyze the function to get a general idea of its behavior.  If you could sketch the graph, you could read the answer off the sketch, right?  I haven't tried to solve the problem, so I don't know how hard it is, but I'm sure this is the right approach.

Comment: By graphing, the equation seems to have 4 solutions which are approximately -1.880479359, 0.04583921619, 1.775641624, 1.868296869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite our equation in the following form: $f(x)=g(x)$, where
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\left(2^x+2^{-x}\right)$$ and $$g(x)=\cos{e^x}.$$

We need $|f(x)|\leq1,$ which gives $$\log_2(2-\sqrt3)\le x\leq\log_2(2+\sqrt3).$$

But for these values of $x$ we see that $g$ decreases and $g$ is a concave function for $x\leq0$.

By the way $f$ is a convex function, decreases on $\left[\log_2(2-\sqrt3),0\right]$ and increases on $\left[0, \log_2(2+\sqrt3)\right]$

Thus, our equation has two roots maximum: one on $\left(\log_2(2-\sqrt3),0\right)$ and one on $\left(0,\log_2(2+\sqrt3)\right)$.

Now, since $f$ and $g$ they are continuous functions, $$f\left(\log_2(2-\sqrt3)\right)>g\left(\log_2(2-\sqrt3)\right),$$
$$f(0)<g(0)$$ and $$f\left(\log_2(2+\sqrt3)\right)>g\left(\log_2(2+\sqrt3)\right),$$
we see that our equation has two roots exactly.